# PHPUnit failed opening required file

Tags: php, phpunit

I've browsed through similar problems on SO, but to no avail. I'm running PHP 5.3.6 and phpunit version 3.6.10. When attempting to execute a simple test:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php'
(include_path='.:/Users/username/pear/share/pear:/usr/lib/php/pear/:/Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit') in ...
```

When reinstalling PHPUnit, I'm not sure if the install location was duplicated, but it appears that when running `which phpunit`, the path is: `/usr/bin/phpunit`. However, it appears to also be installed in `/Users/user/pear/bin/phpunit`. 
I've tried updating all channels and reinstalling PEAR and PHPUnit, but the problem still exists. I'm running on OSX Lion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You made a typo: `'PHPUit/Framework.php'` - the `n` is missing.

Comment: Before re-installing PEAR I would *read* the error message first. It tells you what went wrong. I also told you in the comment above as well.

Comment: @hakre - sorry, that was a typo in me typing out the error (as opposed to copying and pasting). The error is that PHPUnit no longer requires you to explicitly require the Framework class. I somehow was reading old documentation, and I was confused as to why it wasn't working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just remove the line

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
```

and everything should work.

You don't need to `include/require` anything PHPUnit related since (at least) `PHPUnit 3.6`  any more and you can't include that file because it doesn't exist any more in the distribution.

The phpunit runner will take care of bootstrapping everything that is needed by PHPUnit :)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm seeing now. Somehow, apparently, I stumbled onto some old documentation or something on the PHPUnit site, because it was require'ing that file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hahahahaa. It's really great answer.  After I spent hour to fix this problem =) +1 =))

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, Framework.php is not required anymore.

But in any case if you already have too many test files written and having the include statement, then fixing them going to be a cumbersome task. Which was the case I had to face.

If a quick workaround is needed, create an empty Framework.php file. That will resolve the problem.
Create an empty file named Framework.php under your PHPUnit directory. (eg: at: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework.php).

> sudo touch /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework.php